# What is under the Great Sphinx of Giza?

Tags: ancient-egypt

[This video](https://youtu.be/sSepwJGt754) (8:16) shows a tourist displaying a ladder going into an underground shaft at the base of Sphinx.

Just wondering what is inside it and its purpose.

Comment: I suspect it goes to the original ground level? Current ground being the result of millenia of accumulation

Answer (score 9):

Probably sand and limestone and that's about it. The narrator in the video claims that there is a ladder, but it's conspicuously not visible in the shot. It almost seems like a reference to the crackpot theory of a [Hall of Records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_of_Records) or something along these lines.

[An article in Smithsonian Magazine](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/uncovering-secrets-of-the-sphinx-5053442/) describes the extensive archeological work of Mark Lehner:

> In 1977, [Lehner] joined Stanford Research Institute scientists using
>   state-of-the-art remote-sensing equipment to analyze the bedrock under
>   the Sphinx. They found only the cracks and fissures expected of
>   ordinary limestone formations. Working closely with a young Egyptian
>   archaeologist named Zahi Hawass, Lehner also explored and mapped a
>   passage in the Sphinx’s rump, concluding that treasure hunters likely
>   had dug it after the statue was built.

Comment: So I guess Hawass and Lehner just found random shit in that passageway?

Comment: @CMonsour just rubble and sand, most likely.

Answer (score 8):

The small opening shown in the video you link, which a worker covered with what looks like a temporary hatch cover, is probably related to ground water erosion testing and abatement projects. The same [article](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/uncovering-secrets-of-the-sphinx-5053442/) linked by Brian Z has the following section at the end (emphasis mine):

> Today, the Sphinx is still eroding. Three years ago, Egyptian
>   authorities learned that sewage dumped in a nearby canal was causing a
>   rise in the local water table. Moisture was drawn up into the body of
>   the Sphinx and large flakes of limestone were peeling off the statue.
>
> Hawass arranged for **workers to drill test holes in the bedrock around
>   the Sphinx**. They found the water table was only 15 feet beneath the
>   statue. **Pumps have been installed nearby to divert the groundwater.** So
>   far, so good. “Never say to anyone that we saved the Sphinx,” he says.
>   “The Sphinx is the oldest patient in the world. All of us have to
>   dedicate our lives to nursing the Sphinx all the time.”

Another article from 2007 discussing the issue can be read here [Pyramids, Sphinx Threatened by Rising Groundwater](http://www.digitaljournal.com/article/248139).

A more recent article (2012) [Egypt's Sphinx, Pyramids threatened by groundwater, hydrologists warn](http://english.ahram.org.eg/NewsContent/9/40/46972/Heritage/Ancient-Egypt/Egypts-Sphinx,-Pyramids-threatened-by-groundwater,.aspx) discusses some of the measures being taken.

Another You tube video with the sensantionalistic title "Caught Drilling Under the Sphinx...They Know What's Down There!" actually has footage beginning at [time stamp 7:40](https://youtu.be/HVgaD2f8hYI?t=459) showing some workers drilling one of these test holes. Note the proximity to one of the reconstructed areas of the Sphinx, similar to the location shown in the [OPs video](https://youtu.be/sSepwJGt754?t=488).(Note at 8:08 in the OPs video the pipe-like fitting straight out from the mysterious opening).

A video about mysteries under the Sphinx gets many more hits,however, I think the 'mysterious' works under the Sphinx are very un-mysterious plumbing projects meant to monitor and protect it.

UPDATE:
 When I went back to YouTube, the video [Drilling under the Sphinx (Featuring Dr Zahi Hawass and Dr Mark Lehner)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qGzfZHWbZE) was at the top of my recommended list. This short video (3:47) seems to be the source for the footage of the workers, and has Hawass and Lehner discussing the ground water testing/measurement project.